# .htaccess issue, not able to redirect url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-12.04

I have created a .htaccess file, here is the code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule rudra/example/restapi/(.*)$ rudra/example/restapi/MyAPI.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Simply want to rewrite url

```
localhost/rudra/example/restapi/asd/asd/asda
```

to

```
  localhost/rudra/example/restapi/MyAPI.php?request=asd/asd/asda
```

I know it is working ,I have my a2enmod rewrite is on and
AllowOverride All on /var/www/ and
I believe apache is reading this file beacuse if i make any mistake here it is showing error 500 internal server error and
I think my rewrite rule is also right but some how it is unable to rewrite url

in apache2/error.log

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/rudra/example/restapi/example
```

Am I doing any mistake or forgetting something?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the NC flag in a `RewriteRule`, remove it and you'll be fine. Also, you should set the RewriteBase to `/` like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule rudra/example/restapi/(.*)$ rudra/example/restapi/MyAPI.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, be sure that there aren't any spaces between the squere brackets `[]`

Comment: jonan, it is still not working after applying your suggested modification, it is giving me same not found url and one more thing [NC] which I used , correct me if I am wrong but it is telling that url is not case senstive. so why can't I use NC flag in rewrite rule ?

Answer (score 1):

there was the mistake in the the rewriterule, here is the final code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rudra/example/restapi/MyAPI.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I guess this RewriteBase was also missing.

thanks jonan